# When debugging meteor client side, how do you view collection or cursor contents?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm attempting to debug the client side of a [meteor app](http://meteor.com). How do I see the contents of a collection? More specifically, how do I view the contents of a `LocalCollection.Cursor` as I would a plain object in the console?

On the server side, `db.collectionName.find()` will output JSON and `db.collectionName.find().pretty()` makes a collection's contents easy to read and inspect. How would I do something similar on the client side with the 'minimongo' collections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `Collection.find({}).fetch()` to see an array of objects in the collection. Then, you can expand each object to see its properties.

Answer (score 1):

Ya that's true, there is another way of doing that too, 
This is what I was doing MyCollection.find({}); 
 
and in console I go in this manner 
collection->docs->{{your-data-here}}.